# FFMPEG Force overwrite

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I have a C# application calling FFMPEG. Everything is finally starting to work except some people have uploaded different file types with the same name. example being video.mpg and video.mov. FFMPEG is taking the original files and creating a MP4 file out of them with the same name. 
of course when the first file is created it works fine but the second file is created and it requires interaction by me typing "Y" and hitting enter. is there a force overwrite option or a force rename option?

Comment: ffmpeg is not a C# program. And Stack Overflow is not an appropriate site to receive user support for a program like ffmpeg.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-y` forces overwrite. `-n` aborts upon output name collision. There is no auto output rename function.

Comment: Note that `'-y'` must be written before the input argument `'-i'`. For instance, `cmd_out = ['ffmpeg', '-y', '-i', path, path[:-3]+'.wav']`

Comment: Not the case. It can be anywhere except between an option and its value.